# IR LED and Photodiode (G10899-01k) to make NIR sensor

Tags: operational-amplifier, led, infrared, photodiode, transimpedance

I am working on a final project to detect glucose. I am using IR LED of 1200nm spectral wavelength and a photodiode (G10899-01k) of 500nm to 1700nm spectral range.

I have used a transimpedance amplifier in the photovoltaic mode. I get an output of varying from 100mV to 400mV. When passed through the filter, the signal is attenuated to 1.8mV, when amplified, the output does not vary as the out, hence not giving me what I expect.

I kindly request for assistance and guidance on getting a filter that can remove noise; an amplifier to amplify the signal so that the output behave as the input.

Attached is the circuit diagram using LM358 op amp powered by 5V dc supply. IR LED is biased by 1.5V.
[image]

Comment: Edit your question with enough details that people can understand what you have done and what you still need to accomplish.

Comment: Single-supply is a likely problem, but not the only problem.

Comment: You're using a design meant for a negative rail but you don't have one. The opamp you're using requires you to keep input/outputs above the negative voltage, which in this case is ground, but you're not doing that.